# Change the color of the Grid Cell in C#

Tags: c#, colors, grid

I am writing a program for Occupancy grid mapping in C#. I want to change the color of the grid cell.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;


namespace gridappl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Window mainWindow;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            // Create the application's main window

            mainWindow = new Window();
            mainWindow.Title = "Grid Sample";
            // Create the Grid
            Grid myGrid = new Grid();
            myGrid.Width = 600;
            myGrid.Height = 600;
            //myGrid.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            //myGrid.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            myGrid.ShowGridLines = true;


            // Define the Columns
            ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();

            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);


            // Define the Rows
            RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowDef3 = new RowDefinition();

            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);
            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef3);



            // Add the Grid as the Content of the Parent Window Object
            mainWindow.Content = myGrid;
            mainWindow.Show();


        }
    }
}
```

I tried using many commands like the following:

```
myGrid.Background = Brushes.Azure;

myGrid.Background = System.Drawing.Brushes.Red;
```

But still, the program throws errors. What should be done to change the grid cell color as per our choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
{
       for (int j = 0; j < myGrid.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            myGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = /*color you want*/
        }
}
```

Try this to fill backcolor dynamically.

or try this

```
myGrid.Background= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

Comment: Try the second line of code to fill background color for all rows and column cell.

Comment: The second line of code works well in making all the cells of the grid green. How to color specific cells of the grid?

Comment: Could you paste the code where you add your UI element in your grid? So, I can provide solution based on that.

Comment: I have not created any UI element as of now. I wanted to specify in the code itself that specific cells have to be colored

Comment: There is no method available in Grid package to define background for specific cell. But, you can add background to the UIelement which will be displayed above the grid. So, you can achieve the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                myGrid.Rows[i].Cells[/*Cell you want the color*/].Style.BackColor = /*color you want*/
            }
```

The for loop is there in case you want to go through all rows or you can just do

```
myGrid.Rows[/*specific row number*/].Cells[/*Cell you want the color*/].Style.BackColor = /*color you want*/
```

Example:

```
myGrid.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: I added a line like this:   "myGrid.Rows[4].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Azure;" but still the program throws error

Comment: Its because you still need to make it like this `myGrid.Rows[4].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Azure` or `= Color.FromArgb(51, 102, 153);` which I prefer using cause it can adjust how light or dark the color is.

Comment: Now the error is in shown in `Rows`. The error message reads like this: "Grid does not contain definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'Grid' could not be found"

Comment: You have added only 3 rows definition and 3 column definition. Then how can you set backcolor for 4th row? myGrid.Rows[4].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Azure;

Comment: Is it correct to give `Cells[5]` because you have mentioned that we need to enter the number of the *Cell we want to color*.

Comment: As what @ThiyaguRajendran pointed out, You can set the row, column, and cell you want to change the color but it needs to be within the range of existing number of rows and columns in your grid. Your grid is 3x3 based on your code above.

Comment: I get an error while accessing the `Rows` property of `myGrid`. What should be done?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_List.Rows)
{
  if (intcolumncunt == 2)
  {
    if(Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) > Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()))
     {
      row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
     }
  }
}
```